# Send post form to the same page using php or html only

Tags: php, forms, post, get, submit

I can only use php and html to do this.
I'm trying to pass the input of a text box to the URL. Something like this ?input=

The page will be the same.

```
<form method='post' action="">
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <a href="http://example.com?input="<?php echo $_POST['input'] ?>><input type="submit" value="Submit"></a>
    </form>
```

Comment: Doesn't it so what you want as-is?

Comment: `?input=` would require a GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the values to be in the url you need to change the method of your form to get

```
<form method="get" action="">
```

This will cause your url to look something like `http://mydomain.com/index.php?input=something`. All values passed in the URL like this are then accessible via $_GET.

```
<?PHP
  echo $_GET['input'];
?>
```

You don't need the anchor tag as you have it.  Just changing the form will cause the form to submit as you want it.

```
<form method='get' action="">
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to append all form input in the url then you should use  `get` form method.
and you should not use anchor tag because it seems that it is meaningless.

So your form should be like this:

```
<form method='get' action="">
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

After submitting the form you will url like this:

```
http://yousite.com/this_page?input=typed_value
```

you can access your purl params by using global `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` (e.g `$_REQUEST['input']`)